# Where can I find information about which Linux distributions/versions come with the Fuse kernel module?

Tags: history, fuse, distributions

I basically need to know the oldest versions of Linux distributions (with CentOS, RHEL, Debian, Ubuntu, SLES, openSuse, Gentoo being the most important ones) that comes with the Fuse kernel module out of the box.

So far, I have trouble finding information about that listed anywhere. Can someone nudge me to a location?

Comment: It's been in the kernel for over a decade (2.6.14 in 2005), and in distributions for even longer (2002 in Debian). Have you come across distributions you need to support that *don't* have it by default?

Comment: Note that there's a difference between “comes with fuse compiled as a module”, “comes with fuse loaded by default”, and “comes with fuse authorized to users by default”.

Comment: So can I safely assume that every distribution that has a kernel newer than 2.6.14 can use fuse?